# CdpPage.querySelectorAll is not a function while using puphpeteer

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

I was working with [puphpeteer](https://github.com/zoonru/puphpeteer) trying to get some info from an online shopping website. the library is working well and i even took some screenshots from the website and it looks ok. but when i try using the querySelectorAll function to start diggin in the page it shows me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ92j.png)

the code im executing its almost the same as in the examples made by the authors of the library.

```
    $puppeteer = new Puppeteer;
    $browser = $puppeteer->launch();
    $viewport = ['width'=>1920, 'height'=>1080];

    $page = $browser->newPage();
    $page->setViewport($viewport);
    $page->goto('https://www.carrefour.com.ar/arroz?_q=arroz&map=ft');
    $page->waitForNetworkIdle();
    $divs = $page->querySelectorAll('div');

    $browser->close();
```

Any ideas of what could be causing this ??